# Enable lazy buffering in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, buffer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to show video by http data source. but when I set data source, exoplayer immediately start to buffer video, How can start buffering on user play click. 
 
        `val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,Util.getUserAgent(context!!,"user_agent"))
        player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context!!).build()
        playerView!!.player = player
        val contentUrl = "my video url.mp4"
        videoSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(contentUrl))
        player.prepare(videoSource)`


P.S:
I try to change DefaultLoadControl to change buffering behavior but I cant find a workaround.

Thanks.